# He must regret his decision vs He must be regretting his decision

Tags: progressive-aspect, deontic-vs-epistemic, modality

> (1) He must regret his decision.
>
> (2) He must be regretting his decision.

If you're sure that "he" regrets his decision, can you say either (1) or (2)?

In other words, can (2) be interpreted as not having a progressive meaning to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your last question first, it will always be interpreted as having a progressive meaning, that doesn't change.  Sometimes, though, that distinction isn't very meaningful in describing certain situations.  In this example, you can say either 1 or 2 and as a practical matter, the difference in meaning is just a nuance.

Example 1 might describe someone who regrets the decision, but it is not a continuous emotion, the regret is only when he happens to think about it.  Example 2 describes someone who is actively thinking about the decision and regretting it.  The "continuing" aspect does describe something that is different, but it is only a subtle difference in this case.

Your comment mentions another example: "What do you do?" vs. "What are you doing?"  That's a case where the two forms result in an entirely different meaning.  The degree to which the progressive form describes something substantially different in real life is very much a function of the specific word and the context.

You added an interesting additional question in a comment: can (1) also mean "I'm sure that he will regret his decision in the future" instead of "I'm sure that he regrets his decision now"?  Wording your question that way, which is consistent with the comparative meanings in the original question, the answer is no.  You used "must" in the sense of "it is likely".

However, a different meaning of "must" could turn it into a future reference.  If you use "must" to mean a requirement or obligation, "he must regret his decision" could refer to an action expected in the future.  But that's different from what you asked.

Comment: How come they're interchangeable when _He regrets his decision_ and _He is regretting his decision_ are not? One has a progressive meaning and the other doesn't. You don't generally switch between _What do you do?_ and _What are you doing?_, do you?

Comment: I guess I didn't adequately explain.  Yes, the difference is that one has a progressive meaning.  In some cases, the difference will be very meaningful.  In other cases it won't.  "What do you do" vs. "what are you doing" is a case where the meaning is very different.  "He regrets" vs. "he is regretting" or "he must regret" vs. "he must be regretting" are cases where the shift in meaning is much more subtle.  A lot depends on the particular word.  "Regret" is one that describes very similar situations in these different forms, while your last example create two entirely different questions.

Comment: Thanks. Can (1) also mean "I'm sure that he will regret his decision in the future" instead of "I'm sure that he regrets his decision now"?

Comment: @JK2, does the edit more clearly address your question?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks! So the future reference cannot go with an epistemic 'must'? I mean, you cannot say _He must regret his decision tomorrow_ or _He must be regretting his decision tomorrow_ to mean "I'm sure that he will regret his decision tomorrow" or "I'm sure that he will be regretting his decision tomorrow"?

Comment: If you use "must" to mean "it is likely" or "I'm sure", "he must regret" or "he must be regretting" can only mean in the present.  "He must have regretted" would be past tense.  For future tense, "will regret" or "will be regretting", I don't think there's a way to use must with that meaning.  Maybe it's because you can have that certainty only about things that have already happened or are happening now.  "He must regret his decision tomorrow" would mean he's required to do it.  "He must be regretting his decision tomorrow isn't grammatically correct.  (con't)

Comment: You could say "He will be regretting his decision tomorrow" or "he will regret his decision tomorrow". That's actually pretty close in meaning to what "must" does in present tense. Nobody can tell the future, so when you say "he will", it means you're sure he will. You could say "I expect he'll regret it tomorrow", or "it's likely he'll regret it tomorrow", or "I'm sure he'll regret it tomorrow".